# jquery returns last changed checkbox on bulk check/uncheck

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get `data-region-code` attribute from all the checkbox that were changed (checked/unchecked). But with my code, I am getting the last changed checkbox, not all the checkboxes. For eg: If I'm changing checkbox for `data-region-code` `001, 002, 003, 004`, I will get the value as `004` as it is the last changed checkbox. 
For reference: when checkbox is changed, I add `class=changed` for `input`.

Structure (I have more `tr`, maybe around 18-20 with same structure):

```
<table class= settings-container">
  <thead></thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="">
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>
         <input type="checkbox" name="blockage_simulation[]" data-region-code="001" id="blockage_simulation" checked="" class="changed">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="">
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>
         <input type="checkbox" name="blockage_simulation[]" data-region-code="002" id="blockage_simulation" class="changed">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Code:**

```
let regCodeAllRegions = [];
regCodeAllRegions = $('.settings-container').find('input:checkbox.changed').attr('data-region-code');
alert(JSON.stringify(regionCode));
```

Comment: You need to use `.map()` to loop over all the selected elements and return their attrbutes as an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method `attr` only works for a single element, so it returns only the last one. You need to iterate through the list. This is an example:

```js
let regionCodes = [];

$('input:checkbox.changed').each((i, el) => regionCodes.push($(el).data('region-code')));

console.log(regionCodes);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" class="changed" data-region-code="1">
<input type="checkbox" class="changed" data-region-code="2">
<input type="checkbox" class="changed" data-region-code="3">
<input type="checkbox" class="changed" data-region-code="4">
<input type="checkbox" class="changed" data-region-code="5">
```

Another way:

```js
let regionCodes = $('input:checkbox.changed').toArray().map((el) => $(el).data('region-code'));

console.log(regionCodes);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" class="changed" data-region-code="1">
<input type="checkbox" class="changed" data-region-code="2">
<input type="checkbox" class="changed" data-region-code="3">
<input type="checkbox" class="changed" data-region-code="4">
<input type="checkbox" class="changed" data-region-code="5">
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Just one question, is it possible to pass a ternary operator `push` parameter in the first answer? for eg : `$('input:checkbox.changed').each((i, el) => blockSimRegions.push($(el).is(':checked') ? '1' : '0'));`

Comment: @AmanDevrath sure. Inside `each` you can do whatever logic you want prior to add itens to `regionCodes`.